# imageview and listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview with a ImageView that appears when i click on one of the elements of the list.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.valider);
        choiceDialog(view);
    }
```

My layout file for the rows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="1dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"

        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
             android:textSize="15px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_heure"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textSize="15px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />


        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/adresse"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textSize="15px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />



    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that  if I delete an element from the list, the ImageViewe is transferred to the element above whereas it was not clicked at first.

I tried to remove the image when the item is removed like this:

```
resolver.delete(DB_RDVUtils.CONTENT_URI, ligne,null);
ImageView icon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.icon);
icon.setImageResource(0);
```

but in this case, it removes all of the imagesview in the list

How to fix this bug please
Thank you very much

Comment: You should post your layout file.

Comment: You have to show `choiceDialog` and delete methods to make it clearer.

Comment: @Phil thanks , i will update my code with the layout file.  Choicedialog is just a dialog which allow me to delete the row selected

Answer (score 0):

After removing an element from the list, remember to call `Adapter.notifyDataSetchanged()` so the ListView updates correctly.

Comment: Thank you but i tried the notifyDataSetchanged() but it not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
resolver.delete(DB_RDVUtils.CONTENT_URI, ligne,null);
ImageView icon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.icon);
icon. invalidateDrawable(icon.getDrawable());
```

Comment: Yes but he changes nothing . Thanks for your help

Comment: So what class/method do you perform your delete in? Because it is a list, it is probably looping through and deleting all of the icons.

Comment: I just call the delete method of the contentProvider. It delete item by their ID